# Конвертировать docker-compose.yml в Dockerrun.aws.json

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Проект написан на `Django`.
Есть `docker-compose.yml` файл:

```
    version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Я использую `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` от `Amazon`
Дальше начинаются сложности, в документации указано, что есть разница записей мультиконтейнерных приложений и обычных. Но я не понимаю что такое мультиконтейнерное приложение, в самом докере я собрал одно приложение со многими зависимостями, например (файл `requirements.txt`):

```
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
Django==2.0.6
idna==2.7
lxml==4.2.3
pytz==2018.4
requests==2.19.1
urllib3==1.23
```

Это ведь всё собранное, работает в одном контейнере, значит это можно считать не мультиконтейнерным приложением?

В любом случае, так выглядит мой `Dockerrun.aws.json` который работал на простых учебных приложениях, но на моем личном проекте оно не работает:

```
    {
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "2",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "akap/mem_web",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8000"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

Порыв инфу узнал, что нужно конвертировать `docker-compose.yml` в `Dockerrun.aws.json` с помощью этой утилиты  https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform, но не понимаю как она работает.

Comment: а вопрос в том, как конкретно работает та утилита?

Comment: можно и без неё) главное, понять, как сделать так чтобы все работало, суть саму, а то  в учебных приложениях вроде все понятно, а вот на своем уже не выходит.

Comment: @Romikromikromik утилита работает, в README написано как запустить в докере (cat docker-compose.yml | docker run --rm -i micahhausler/container-transform -o ecs). Попробуйте установить docker и просто выполнить в консоли команду. Или давайте ошибки при запуске в AWS Elastic Beanstalk так будет проще разобраться